# Simple perl file copy methods without using File::Copy

Tags: perl, filehandle, file-copying

I have very little perl experience and have been trying a few methods on OS X before I attempt to use Macperl on a more difficult to access OS 9 with very limited memory.

I have been trying simple file copy methods without using File::Copy.

Both of the following appear to work:

```
open R,"<old"; 
open W,">new"; 
print W <R>; 

open $r,"<old"; 
open $w,">new"; 
while (<$r>) { print $w $_ }
```

Why can't I use $r and $w with the first method?

How does the first method work without a 'while'?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a better way to do this?

There sure is... `File::Copy` is a core module (no installation requred), so there's little reason to avoid using it.

```
use File::Copy;
copy('old', 'new');
```

Alternatively, you can use a system call to the underlying OS, in your case, OS-X

```
system('cp', 'old', 'new');
```

**UPDATE** Oops, you're on OS9, so I'm not sure what system calls are available.

You can use your first method with lexical file handles, but you need to disambiguate a little.

```
open $r, '<', 'old';
open $w, '>', 'new';
print {$w} <$r>;
```

Bare in mind this is unidiomatic code, and if you just want to create a direct copy, the first method is preferable (**EDIT** If your memory constraints allow for it).

Comment: If would be useful to know if the OS 9 memory requirements are likely to differ significantly for the various methods on this page.

Comment: My concern with OS 9 is that it does not have protected memory like OS X - I would prefer it not to crash when the file size increases.

Answer (score 1):

Perl operators and functions can return different things depending on what their context expects.

The first method works because the print function creates what is called a list context for the <> operator - then thee operator will "slurp in" the entire file.

In the second example, the <> operator is called in the condition of the loop, which creates a scalar context, returning one line at a time (some asterisks here, but that's another story.)

Here is some explanation about contexts: http://perlmaven.com/scalar-and-list-context-in-perl.

And, both methods should work with the R and W filehandles (which are old fashioned Perl filehandles that are different from regular variables), and with the $r/$w notation that actually denotes variables which hold a filehandle *reference*. The difference is subtle but in most everyday use cases these can be used interchangeably. Have you tried using $ variables in the first example?

Comment: Will the 'slurp' attempt to use more memory in OS 9 (PPC not iOS) than the other method?

Comment: Now that I have added parentheses to the first one they both work with both types of filehandle.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the Hellmar Becker's answer:

The `print $w <$r>;` does not work (gives a syntax error) because if the FILEHANDLE argument is a variable, perl tries to interpret the `print`'s argument list beginning (`$w <$r`) as an operator (see the NOTE in http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html). To disambigue put parentheses around the `<$r>`:

```
print $w (<$r>);
```

Comment: Thanks - that fixes it